# macOS – find the location of .sty for beamer themes

Tags: beamer, mactex, themes, tlmgr

Title.

I want to create my own theme but I first need to go where all beamer themes are installed on my Mac but I can't find them. I installed with MacTeX and `tlmgr` is present.

Thanks.

Comment: look at the log  of any beamer document and the full path will be there, but do not put your personal theme in the main mactex tree

Comment: Sounds like an xy-problem. If your actual question is where to place your own theme, then this is a possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Where should I put it until I have a correct version to publish it on CTAN? On the same location of my .tex test file?

Comment: @Mordecai Same location as your tex file is an easy solution. Alternative, place it in your texmf folder, see the liked question.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried several paths given in the thread you linked but It doesn't seems to work in 2022. For instance, texmf in ``~/Library/``doesn't exist and I only have texlive which doesn't contain anything interesting.

Comment: `~/Library/texmf` is not created by default. You must create it and the necessary tree structure within it yourself.

Comment: @Mordecai Start at the beginning of the accepted answer: what directory does  `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` give you?

Comment: @HerbSchulz That's indeed a good reason It doesn't appear in the file tree haha!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It gives me ``/Users/$USER/Library/texmf`` but indeed, I didn't know It wasn't created automatically.

Comment: @Mordecai Sounds good. Don't forget to create a `tex` folder inside it and then inside the `tex` folder a `latex` folder.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'll do that, don't hesitate to write an answer with the fact that the folder doesn't exist by default and I have to create it, I'll mark it as official answer if you wish :)

Comment: @Mordecai I think it would be better to mark your question as duplicate. This will make sure that future users with the same problem, will find the linked post more easily.